# how can i get data from webservice in jsp

Tags: web-services, jsp, liferay

This is part of my view.jsp:

```
<form action="some_test_url" method="GET">
<input type="hidden" name="operation" value="sumoketos_sumos" />
<input type="text" name="kodas">
<input type="submit" value="Ieškoti" />
</form>
```

Im getting this result in the new page:
{"id":"102061","metai":"2015","suma":"-2627.3"}
How can i put this data to the table on the same view.jsp page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a resourceUrl and perform the action in an ajax. Then in the response, use javascript to place that information in your table.